# Should I enable autocorrect on a name text field for a sign up view in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Would that annoy users, or does autocorrect work well with entering names in? I've seen on other apps that there is autocorrect enabled on their name text fields, but I don't know if that is such a good idea.

Comment: What does it matter if it's written in Swift or Objective C or D or J++?

Comment: A question of this nature is probably better suited to [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITextField` `Autocorrection` is very useful for end users.
User can enter details with in single click

And also you can set `texField.contentType` it’s more easy to fill user details in form design

[uitextfieldcontenttype](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextcontenttype?language=objc)